# Cygwin and Git: getting "fatal: error in line 1:"

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm using the latest version of Git available for the latest version of Cygwin.  About half the time when pulling from some remote, I get the following error:

> fatal: Error in line 1:

A full trace produces the following:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git pull -v upstream master
trace: exec: 'git-pull' '-v' 'upstream' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull' '-v' 'upstream' 'master'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'branch.master.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '-v' '--update-head-ok' 'upstream' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@redacted.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''Project/project.git'\'''
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
From redacted.com:Project/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fmt-merge-msg'
fatal: Error in line 1:
```

Has anyone run into this problem?  And if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Is that the last line of the error output? What kinds of remotes are you trying to pull from? Do you have your RSA keys set up? Any further information would make helping easier :)

Comment: That is the last line of the output.  The remote is a GitHub installation.  All the keys are good.  Unfortunately that really is all the info I have to give.  Things work great in msysgit, but I'd rather use Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I have also observed this problem on Cygwin 1.7.9 on Windows 7. Somehow `.git/FETCH_HEAD` becomes corrupt. This happens with remotes that fetch via SSH and also on the same host.

For a workaround, consider an excerpt from the [`git pull` documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-pull.html):

> In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

To avoid having to read `FETCH_HEAD`, name your branch explicitly. For example, assuming you’re on `master` and tracking `origin/master`, execute the following sequence to get the same effect as `git pull`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/master
```

---

I thought this problem was sporadic, but I’m having trouble to get it to succeed at all lately.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub usage {
  <<EOUsage;
Usage: $0 [how-many]

  where how-many is a positive integer (default: 100)
EOUsage
}

$0 =~ s!^.*/!!;
my $howmany = @ARGV ? shift : 100;
die usage if @ARGV || $howmany !~ /^ (?!0+$) \d+$/x;

my $bad;
for (1 .. $howmany) {
  unlink ".git/FETCH_HEAD";
  my $output = `git fetch -v 2>&1`;
  die "$0: git fetch exited ", ($? >> 8), ":\n", $output if $?;

  ++$bad unless system("git rev-parse -q --verify FETCH_HEAD") == 0;
}

my $pct = sprintf "%d%%", ($bad/$howmany) * 100;
print "$0: fetches=$howmany, bad=$bad ($pct)\n";
```